# SQL Server Record Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
Select distinct 'R' + cast(f.ProjID as VarChar(20)) + '_' + cast(WS.Name as varchar(25)) + '_' + cast(f.catID as varchar(25)) + '_' + cast(spl.CompID as Varchar(25)) as DocNumber, 
    f.Quantity, 
    spl.PartName, 
    ct.Name as Section
from equipment.dbo.fixture f 
Join Equipment.dbo.ScoutPartsList spl on f.PartID = spl.ID 
Join Category ct on f.CatID = ct.id 
Join Store S ON F.StoreID= S.ID 
Join Store WS ON S.WarehouseID = WS.ID 
Where f.ProjID=6715 and f.Catid=4715
```

This is my Result:

```
   DocNumber         Quantity         PartName                    Section
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    0   Trion 20" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    1   Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    2   Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    4   Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    5   Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    8   Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    10  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    11  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    12  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    13  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    16  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    20  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    21  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    22  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    23  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    24  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    25  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    30  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    31  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    35  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    38  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    45  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    50  Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
```

I would like to Sum the quantity colummn and group by the doc number.
So if there were two types of parts for one doc number I would only have two results (One for each part with the sum of thos parts) instead of bunches.

Expected Result (quantities not actually correct):

```
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    124 Trion 20" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
R6715_AZ A_4715_1831    364 Trion 22" Pusher (Frozen Potato)    FROZEN POTATO
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Have you tried adding `GROUP BY` for the columns you were interested in and applying a `SUM` to the `Quantity` column?

Comment: Are you familiar with the GROUP BY and SUM() statements in SQL?

Comment: Yes I know group by and sum but you cant group by only one column

Comment: @michaelhanon you **can** group by any number of columns, as long as you put all those columns on the `GROUP BY` clause. Also, your question actually says you want to group by both doc number AND part type.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
WITH DATA
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 'R' + CAST(f.ProjID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '_' + CAST(WS.Name AS VARCHAR(25)) + '_' + CAST(f.catID AS VARCHAR(25)) + '_' + CAST(spl.CompID AS VARCHAR(25)) AS DocNumber
         ,f.Quantity
         ,spl.PartName
         ,ct.Name as Section
    FROM equipment.dbo.fixture AS F
    JOIN Equipment.dbo.ScoutPartsList spl 
        ON f.PartID = spl.ID 
    JOIN Category ct 
        ON f.CatID = ct.id 
    JOIN Store S 
        ON F.StoreID= S.ID 
    JOIN Store WS 
        ON S.WarehouseID = WS.ID 
    WHERE f.ProjID=6715 AND f.Catid=4715
)
SELECT DocNumber
      ,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
      ,PartName
      ,MAX(Section) AS Section
FROM DATA
GROUP BY DocNumber, PartName;
```

Comment: This is close, but the second select does not display all the columns of the original query, when I add them I get the usual group by error. No contained in group by clause.

Comment: That edit is even closer, but as you see above there is two different types of parts 20" and 22". The result only displays the 22" part. I need to group by both the part and doc numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DocNumber, SUM(Quantity) Quantity, PartName, Section
FROM (
Select distinct 'R' + cast(f.ProjID as VarChar(20)) + '_' + cast(WS.Name as varchar(25)) + '_' +     cast(f.catID as varchar(25)) + '_' + cast(spl.CompID as Varchar(25)) as DocNumber, 
    Quantity, 
    spl.PartName, 
    ct.Name as Section
from equipment.dbo.fixture f 
Join Equipment.dbo.ScoutPartsList spl on f.PartID = spl.ID 
Join Category ct on f.CatID = ct.id 
Join Store S ON F.StoreID= S.ID 
Join Store WS ON S.WarehouseID = WS.ID 
Where f.ProjID=6715 and f.Catid=4715
)
Group by DocNumber, PartName, Section
```

SQL Server tells you that some columns are not contained in the group clause because you need to include in the `Group By` clause all columns that are not grouped. In this case you want to group by all columns but quantity, so that's what you need to tell to SQL Server...

Comment: Thank you, I received an error. It seems you cannot group by an alias, I had to group by all the concatenated columns.

Comment: Weird... that's actually why I put your original query as a subquery, so you could use the name directly instead of all columns. That's also why king.code created a CTE...

Answer (score 0):

### Resolved.

Group By alias was wrong on my end.

```
Select distinct 'R' + cast(f.ProjID as VarChar(20)) + '_' + cast(WS.Name as varchar(25)) + '_' + cast(f.catID as varchar(25)) + '_' + cast(spl.CompID as Varchar(25)) as DocNumber, sum(f.Quantity), spl.PartName, ct.Name as Section
    from equipment.dbo.fixture f 
    Join Equipment.dbo.ScoutPartsList spl on f.PartID = spl.ID 
    Join Category ct on f.CatID = ct.id 
    Join Store S ON F.StoreID= S.ID 
    Join Store WS ON S.WarehouseID = WS.ID 
    Where f.ProjID=6715 and f.Catid=4715
    Group By f.ProjID, ws.Name, f.catID, spl.CompId, spl.PartName, ct.Name
```

Comment: Indeed a query is evaluated in this order: FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> SELECT -> ORDER BY. You cannot group by a column alias because it is evaluated only in the SELECT statement.